# ClickOnce application requires network connection to start even with update check disabled

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have a ClickOnce application that:

- Is available offline (installed) - Properties->Publish->This application is available offline...
- Is told never to check for updates (I do them myself) - Properties->Publish->Updates->Untick The application should check for updates.

I have published the application and it is installed on about 60 of our PCs. I use a batch script to run the `.appref-ms` file on startup (have also tried this by running the `.application` too but with the same result).

I have noticed that sometimes on startup the application fails to start (I guess it's beating the network to the punch and starting before we have internet).

I have confirmed this by trying the run the application on a PC with no network and get the same error:

> Application download did not succeed. Check your network connection, or contact your system administrator or network service providor.

Looking in the log file this is because ClickOnce is trying to download the `.application` file from my server rather than running the application locally.

I have double checked the .application and it is missing the subscription element which I believe disabled automatic updates.

Anyone have any ideas what is going on here?

Thanks in advance